# Akka HTTP encountering Dead Letters

Tags: java, akka

I'm developing a simple REST API using Akka HTTP using java. After successful completion of request-response cycle getting some info like this.

```html
[INFO] [01/30/2019 10:35:04.176] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2] Message [akka.io.TcpConnection$Unregistered$] from Actor[akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2#-1193182068] to Actor[akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2#-1193182068] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/2#-1193182068]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

If this is normal I want to stop printing this on my console. If this is somekind of error; how to handle it? This is my code.

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
Function<HttpRequest, HttpResponse> requestHandler = new Function<HttpRequest, HttpResponse>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public HttpResponse apply(HttpRequest request) throws Exception {

            return HttpResponse.create().withEntity("HelloWorld");
        }};
Source<IncomingConnection, CompletionStage<ServerBinding>> serverSource = Http.get(system)
       .bind(ConnectHttp.toHost("0.0.0.0", 8080), materializer);
CompletionStage<ServerBinding> serverBindingFuture = serverSource.to(Sink.foreach(connection -> {
        System.out.println("Accepted new connection from " + connection.remoteAddress());
        connection.handleWithSyncHandler(requestHandler, materializer);

        })).run(materializer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a custom Config to the actor system solved my problem.

```html
final Config config = ConfigFactory.load().withValue("akka.log-dead-letters", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("off"));
                    
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mysystem", config);
```

Comment: this is too brutal, you wouldn't want to disable dead letters logging just because of that. this is already solved here - https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/26300 in 2.5.22